# Header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: angular

**Angular 2:**

```js
import { Injectable, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormsModule, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms'
import { Http, Response, Headers, HttpModule, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    selector: 'message-notofication',
    templateUrl: './messageNotification.html',
    styleUrls: ['./messageNotification.css']
})

@Injectable() 
export class emailNotification {
    constructor(private http:Http) { }
    userForm = new FormGroup ({
        msg_name: new FormControl(),
        msg_details: new FormControl()
    });
    onFrmSubmit(){
        let urlUpto = 'http://ncfkdevweb01/POSAlertWebService/api/';
        let data = {
            "NotificationID": "0",
            "SubmitedEmail": "vasanth@gmail.com",
            "PublishEmail": "vasanth1@gmail.com",
            "ErrorEmail": "Telecom",
            "Module": "1"
        }
        const headers = new Headers();
        let body = JSON.stringify(data);
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});  
          return this.http.put( urlUpto + "POSAlertEmailNotificiation/UpdateInsertNotificationEmail", body, options)
          .subscribe(()=>{},
              err =>console.log(err)
          );
    } 
}
```

The above code using for `PUT service call` in `angular 2`. And from the server side we are allow the `CORS` in `web.config` file.

But still i am unable to fix this [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YRYD.png) like showing "*header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response*"

Comment: web.config: `<customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>`

Comment: In your HttpHeaders remove the Access-Control-Allow_origin header headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); Just make sure this is set on the server to allow requests from different origins. When you remove the  header it's likely going to complain about Allow-Credentials header too. Comment thise lines and lets see.

Comment: It seems to be a backend issue. Can you let me know which language is used in the backend?